# I need help for getting SQLite data

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I use this method for retrieving my data

```
 public String getdata() {
 String[] columns= new String[]{RowId,RowBusinessName};
 Cursor c=OurDatabase.query(TableName,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
 String Result="";
 int iRowId=c.getColumnIndex(RowId);
 int iRowBusinessName=c.getColumnIndex(RowBusinessName);
 for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
 Result=Result+c.getString(iRowBusinessName)+"\n";
 }
 return Result;

}
```

How can I make it return structured data (id & business_name)?
I want to display every business_name in a single textview.

Please help

Comment: so you want to return List<YOUR_OBJECT> by calling getData()  or just normal String?

Comment: create an object class, use set method to set data into object, return the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, here is the solution if you want to get only 1 `RowBusinessName` returned as a `String`. (Hoping that your RowBusinessName is type `String`).

```
public String getdata(int rowId) {

     String[] columns= new String[]{RowId,RowBusinessName};
     Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLENAME, columns, RowId + "=?", new String[]{rowId + ""}, null, null, null, null);         

     String Result="";

     if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
         // not required though
         int rowId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RowId));

         String rowBusinessName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RowBusinessName));

         result = rowBusinessName;
     }
     return result;
}
```

Now if you want a list of RowBusinessName, then you have to build a `List<String>` rather than appending it to `Result`. That's not really a good way!

```
public List<String> getAll() {
        List<String> businessNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] columns= new String[]{RowId,RowBusinessName};

        Cursor c=OurDatabase.query(TableName,columns,null,null,null,null,null);

        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            // loop until the end of Cursor and add each entry to Ticks ArrayList.
            do {
                String businessName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RowBusinessName));
                if (businessName != null) {
                    businessNameList.add(businessName);
                }
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        return businessNameList;
    }
```

These are work around. 
The appropriate answer would be to create an Object that holds `id` and `businessName`. That way, you build an object from DB and just return the entire Object.

Comment: Thank You For Your Help , i am a beginner , can u give me an example for creating an object from db, I want to return id,business_name

Comment: Check it out [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/)